# Calculator function is not working, is showing function undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Below funtion not working and showing "add is undefined". I am calculating by chaining the function calls.

```
var calc = {
  x: 5,
  add: function(num) {
    x = x + num;
    return x;
  },
  sub: function(num) {
    x = x - num;
    return x;
  },
  set: function(num) {
    x = num;
    return x;
  },
  print: function() {
    console.log(x);
  }
}
calc.set(5).add(3).sub(2).add(10).print();
```

Comment: To chain this way you have to return the object, not `x`

Comment: calc.set(5) returns a number. Numbers dont have methods. For method chaining, you have to return this.

Comment: in both the cases i am not getting the result  @Jasper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return reference to `calc` instead of number to allow chaining, also use `this` to reference `x` value:

```js
var calc = {
  x : 5,
  add: function(num){
    this.x = this.x+num;
    return this;
  },
  sub :function(num){
    this.x =this.x-num;
    return this;
  },
  set :function(num){
    this.x= num;
    return this;
  },
  print : function(){
    console.log(this.x);
  }
}
calc.set(5).add(3).sub(2).add(10).print();
```

Here is ES6 version with `class` syntax:

```js
class Calc {

  constructor(x = 0) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  add(num) {
    this.x = this.x + num;
    
    return this;
  }
  
  sub(num) {
    this.x = this.x - num;
    
    return this;
  }
  
  set(num) {
    this.x = num;
    
    return this;
  }
  
  print() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }

}

new Calc().set(5).add(3).sub(2).add(10).print();

// or with constructor
new Calc(5).add(3).sub(2).add(10).print();
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy! That worked! Anyway can do this in es6

Comment: Sure, will add ES6 version

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do this :

```js
var Calc = function (x) {
  this.x = x;
};

Calc.prototype = {
  add: function (y) {
    this.x += y;
    return this;
  },
  sub: function (y) {
    this.x -= y;
    return this;
  },
  valueOf: function () {
    return this.x;
  },
  toString: function () {
    return (+this) + "";
  },
  print : function () {
    console.log(this.toString());
    return this;
  }
};

function calc (x) {
  return new Calc(x);
}

calc(1).add(
  calc(5).add(3).sub(2).add(10).print()
).print();
```